# Are there any recommendations for request codes values in Android?

Tags: android

Now I am using random numbers for request codes. So, every time I add new activity for startActivityForResult I need to check all other such activities to avoid collisions. May be there are any practices for defining values, non-collidable by design? 
What do you think?

Comment: I just use random numbers (generated at compile time), and never had any issues - but this is a good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you still need to check the result of an activity and like the visually polished structures please check this method.

Declare the internal class inside your activity class:

```
class RequestCode {
    static final int IMPORT = 100;
    static final int WRITE_PERMISSION = 101;
}
```

Use a code when starting activity:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.IMPORT);
```

Check the result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RequestCode.IMPORT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Actually you don't need to check all your Activities and it doesn't matter much if you've the same values in different Activities.

The idea for the request codes is that you, in your Activity X, in `onActivityResult()` can distinguish between the results of different requests you started with `startActivityForResult()`.

So if you have 3 different `startActivityForResult()` calls in your activity, you'll need 3 different request codes in order to be able to distinguish between them in `onActivityResult()` - so you can tell which *result* belongs to which *start*. But if you have another Activity Y where you're doing something similar, it doesn't matter when the request codes there are the same like in Activity X.

Comment: This is a great answer. It cuts to the root of the problem, which is understanding why you need the request codes in the first place, and that they don't need to be globally unique. Presumably, this is in the documentation somewhere, but if it is I didn't see it.

Comment: Even though this answer is valid, I think it's good practice to always use different `REQUEST_CODE` for all your activities. Whenever you import a functionality into an activity, you want to be sure the request code is different without needing to check all the `startActivityForResult() ` calls in that specific activity/fragments

Comment: @MarioLenci but to have all different request codes you'd have to check all startActivityForResult() in all your activities and fragments, not just one.